# Нарисовать закрашенный QPolygonF в Qt3D

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

У меня есть функция, которая возвращает QPolygonF, который мне нужно нарисовать и заполнить каким-нибудь цветом.
Гугл выдал функцию отрисовки линии, основанную на OpenGL, которую я поменял на отрисовку LinesLoop.

Есть какой-то более изящный способ рисовки? 
Или нужно именно через OpenGL рисовать такие вот полигончики? Как можно закрасить этот LinesLoop или надо что-то другое использовать?

```
void MainWindow::drawPolygon(const QPolygonF polygon, QColor color, Qt3DCore::QEntity *_rootEntity)
{
    int numOfVertices = polygon.size();
    auto *geometry = new Qt3DRender::QGeometry(_rootEntity);

    // position vertices
    QByteArray bufferBytes;
    bufferBytes.resize(3 * numOfVertices * static_cast<int>(sizeof(QPointF)));
    float *positions = reinterpret_cast<float*>(bufferBytes.data());
    for(auto point : polygon){
        *positions++ = static_cast<float>(point.x());
        *positions++ = 0.0f; //We need to drow only on the surface
        *positions++ = static_cast<float>(point.y());
    }

    auto *buf = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(geometry);
    buf->setData(bufferBytes);

    auto *positionAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(geometry);
    positionAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName());
    positionAttribute->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
    positionAttribute->setVertexSize(3);
    positionAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    positionAttribute->setBuffer(buf);
    positionAttribute->setByteStride(3 * sizeof(float));
    positionAttribute->setCount(static_cast<unsigned int>(numOfVertices));//(2);
    geometry->addAttribute(positionAttribute); // We add the vertices in the geometry

    // connectivity between vertices
    QByteArray indexBytes;
    indexBytes.resize(numOfVertices * static_cast<int>(sizeof(unsigned int))); // start to end
    unsigned int *indices = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(indexBytes.data());
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < static_cast<unsigned int>(numOfVertices); ++i) {
        *indices++ = i;
    }

    auto *indexBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(geometry);
    indexBuffer->setData(indexBytes);

    auto *indexAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(geometry);
    indexAttribute->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::UnsignedInt);
    indexAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::IndexAttribute);
    indexAttribute->setBuffer(indexBuffer);
    indexAttribute->setCount(static_cast<unsigned int>(numOfVertices));
    geometry->addAttribute(indexAttribute); // We add the indices linking the points in the geometry

    // mesh
    auto *poly = new Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer(_rootEntity);
    poly->setGeometry(geometry);
    poly->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::LineLoop);
    auto *material = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(_rootEntity);
    material->setAmbient(color);

    // entity
    auto *lineEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(_rootEntity);
    lineEntity->addComponent(poly);
    lineEntity->addComponent(material);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, решил так:
Поменял в своей функции drawPolygon ее имя на drawTriangles и строчку  `poly->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::LineLoop);` заменил на  `poly->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Triangles);`, чтобы функция отрисовывала треугольники.

Далее, используя "header-only" библиотеку отсюда https://github.com/mapbox/earcut.hpp я написал простенькую функцию для триангуляции (деления полигона на много треугольников)

```
QPolygonF MainWindow::triangulateQPolygonF(QPolygonF polygon) {

    using Coord = double;
    using N = uint32_t;
    // Create array
    using Point = std::array<Coord, 2>;
    std::vector<std::vector<Point>> vecVecPolygon;
    std::vector<Point> vecPolygon;

    for(auto point : polygon) {
        vecPolygon.push_back({point.x(), point.y()});
    }

    vecVecPolygon.push_back(vecPolygon);

    std::vector<N> indices = mapbox::earcut<N>(vecVecPolygon);

    QPolygonF resPolygon;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < indices.size(); ++i) {
        resPolygon << QPointF((vecPolygon[indices[i]])[0], //x coordinate
                (vecPolygon[indices[i]])[1]); //y coordinate
    }

    return resPolygon;
}
```

И все. Теперь просто пишу в программе что-то, наподобии `drawTriangles(triangulateQPolygonF(polygon), QColor(Qt::black), entity);`

Стоит иметь в виду, что отрисовываться будут только треугольники, у которых вершины указаны в `polygon` в порядке "по часовой стрелке". В ином случае они будут невидимы спереди. Чтобы изменить это поведение, можно воспользоваться https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qt3drender-qcullface.html#details (`Qt3DRender::QCullFace::NoCulling` для отображения по часовой и против). Я так и не разобрался, как правильно использовать этот класс, но у себя криво реализовал, основываясь на коде в ответе отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818584/2d-meshes-in-qt3d